# What to hide when open sourcing an iOS app?

Tags: ios, github, open-source

I am building an app which I would like to push to GitHub and make it public as an open source project.

What would I need to hide?

I can only think of any API-keys.

Should the bundle ID be hidden?

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Bundle Id should also be hidden as the certificates created by your account on the Apple's website will be available to the Bundle ID which you have created.

Comment: An app's bundle id has nothing to do with your certificates. There is no need to hide the app's bundle id. And how can you hide it? It's in the Info.plist. That file is needed for everyone to build the app. There is no security issue with the bundle id.